# Projecting GCP points into translated file

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I have file A.png and file B.png. I translate file A.png so i could translate it into B.png (creating multilayer file). Is there any easy way to get new GCP points coordinates so i could combine those 2 images correctly? I've done so far using only GDAL binaries. Can I somehow use only binaries to do this? If not, is there any easy way do do it?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish though. Are you try to make both the images align with each other?

Comment: I have 2 images with diffrent resolution and diffrent orientation. I can warp them to have same resolution and orientation but I would loose corresponding points due to gdalwarp transformation. I just need at least 1 corresponding point (like 1 gcp point but after i warp one image).

Comment: I'm more interested to know why you choose png over a more specialized geo format (like geotiff)

Answer (score 1):

you can use gdal_translate binary to add the GCPs using -gcp flag and then use gdalwarp to tranform the image using those gcps.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing but I cannot combine them into one because corresponding points (GCP points) are lost due to gdalwarp transformation of one of the images.